# Can I cast spells with one hand and wield a sword with another?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

I’m starting to play as Hexblade warlock and I have some kind of a brain lag. Can I wield a sword and cast spells with my free hand? Since my sword can be a spellcasting focus and I can perform somatic components with my free hand?

Comment: I assume you're getting the "my sword can be a spellcasting focus" part from the Improved Pact Weapon invocation from Xanathar's Guide to Everything? Note that it has the Pact of the Blade feature as a prerequisite, so it can only be chosen at level 3 or higher.

Comment: Related: [How do foci and somatic+material components interact when it comes to occupying a hand?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46201/how-do-foci-and-somaticmaterial-components-interact-when-it-comes-to-occupying), [Casting a Somatic, non-Material spell while holding a focus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105480/casting-a-somatic-non-material-spell-while-holding-a-focus), [How can I cast spells as a Hexblade Warlock while using a sword and shield?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111248/how-can-i-cast-spells-as-a-hexblade-warlock-while-using-a-sword-and-shield)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes and you don't even need the free hand if the spell requires both material and somatic components

From Somatic components

> Spellcasting gestures might include a forceful gesticulation or an intricate set of gestures. If a spell requires a somatic component, the caster must have free use of **at least one hand** to perform these gestures.

From Material components

> A spellcaster must have a hand free to access a spell’s material components — **or to hold a spellcasting focus** — but it **can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic components.**

(all **emphasis** mine)