# Is the War Caster feat effectively required for a sword-and-board Hexblade/Paladin multiclass?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, character-creation, optimization, spell-components

In our next campaign I want to play a **Hexblade - Vengeance Paladin multiclass**.
The campaign will eventually reach the high levels. I want my final level split to be **14** levels in **Hexblade** and **6** in **Paladin**. I want to play this, both so that we don't die all the time, and for story reasons. 
I can post the backstory later, if that is helpful.

I want my character to be the **tank** for our group, so I want to use heavy armor, and a shield with a longsword. However, I have noticed, that I can not really cast spells this way. With the holy symbol and the Improved Pact Weapon invocation, I can ignore material components eventually, although a bit late for my taste.

What worries me more are the **somatic components** of spells. Many of the spells I want to use, such as *hold person*, *mirror image*, and *shadow of moil* require somatic components.

I want my character to be a half elf, so I want to take the Elven Accuracy feat at level 4. My next feat would be at level 10. At that point, I can take the **War Caster** feat. That is very late though.

**Is there any way to cast spells with somatic components for me, without using War Caster**, or do I have to give up my shield?

Comment: follow up question: Could I sheath my sword, then cast a spell? Does this require a bonus action, or could I just do it during my action (my reaction spells don't require somatic cmomponents, so I don't care about that)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. We have a general guideline of [1 question per post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/1-post-1-question-is-it-a-rule-or-a-guideline-or-what). If you have a new question, you should [ask](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) it separately (but make sure to search to make sure it hasn't already been asked).

Comment: Related (some might be possible duplicates): [How does War Caster interact with Hexblade?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130933/how-does-war-caster-interact-with-hexblade), [Can Hexblade warlocks use a staff and shield?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138447/can-hexblade-warlocks-use-a-staff-and-shield), [Can a wizard using an arcane focus quarterstaff and a shield still cast somatic component spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105402/can-a-wizard-using-an-arcane-focus-quarterstaff-and-a-shield-still-cast-somatic)

Comment: worth noting that Hold Person is VSM, and thus lets you use your spellcasting focus hand just fine.  The others are, admittedly, more porblematic.  On the other hand, Shadow of Moil requires an expensive component, so even Warcaster wont' help you there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Free object interaction is your friend

Each of your turns can include one so-called ["free object interaction"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn):

> Your turn can include a variety of flourishes that require neither your action nor your move.
>
> [...]
>
> You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or your action. For example, you could open a door during your move as you stride toward a foe, or you could draw your weapon as part of the same action you use to attack.
>
> If you want to interact with a second object, you need to use your action. Some magic items and other special objects always require an action to use, as stated in their descriptions.

One of the examples given is drawing your weapon prior to taking the attack action. Similarly, sheathing your weapon should be a valid free object interaction. On any given turn, you can draw your weapon and take the attack action, or sheathe your weapon and use your now-free hand to cast a warlock spell, using a component pouch to supply the material components if necessary. This should have you covered for most combat actions you would want to take.

### More general item-juggling issues

There are some actions that will still be problematic, such as pulling out a magic item and using your action to activate it, because if you are currently holding a sword, sheathing it and pulling out an item is 2 object interactions, not 1. To get around this, you'll either need to drop the sword before fetching the other item, or spend your action to fetch the item after sheathing your sword. However, these are not issues specific to a paladin/warlock multiclass–they are problematic for *any* character with both hands occupied. If you know on the previous turn what you're planning to do next turn, you can use your free object interaction at the end of the previous turn to sheathe your sword, then use your free object interaction on the start of the next turn to draw the other item. And of course, if your last action was casting a spell rather than attacking with a sword, your hand is likely free and you can pull out an item and activate it with no problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! We don't really use magic items, so that is not a problem. My warlock focus is ofc my sword, so I need to keep that in my hand. Can I stow my shield in a similar way? Or can I just drop it and pick it up again?

Comment: What you said seems to be "legal" to me. However, I don't understand what the somatic part of the warcaster feat is for then. Is it just to be able to move after casting and interact with another object? I am a bit worried about "cheating" by using the upside of a shield without paying the price for it...

Comment: @JonathanBöcker A shield is strapped to your arm and requires an action to equip/unequip. Regarding the war caster feature, keep in mind there are other costs to sheathing your weapon, such as losing the ability to make attacks of opportunity with it. And sometimes you really need that free object interaction for something like opening a door along the path of your movement to avoid being slowed down, or pressing the macguffin release button. Being able to perform somatic components without freeing your hands makes the logistics of spellcasting while armed much simpler.

Comment: Thank you. So to cast warlock spells, I would need to buy a seperate focus (other than my blade), stow my weapon, cast with the other focus, and draw the weapon again in the next round?

Comment: @JonathanBöcker I would recommend a component pouch rather than an arcane focus, since you don't need to draw or stow it.

Comment: "There are some actions that will still be problematic, such as pulling out a magic item and using your action to activate it, because if you are currently holding a sword, sheathing it and pulling out an item is 2 object interactions, not 1." - Note that you could drop an item for no action cost... Though picking it back up at some point will still require a free object interaction. (It's also worth noting that a second object interaction on your turn after the free one requires the Use an Object action.)

Comment: No need to sheath and unsheathe your sword all the time, you can drop the sword for free and pick it up with object interaction. Better yet you can prop it against yourself while you are casting. Of course you can't move around, but it will save you an interaction when you don't have any to spend.

Comment: Sorry, that I have to bother you again, but I have another question:  Do I even need improved pact weapon this way, to provide material components of a spell? I would need to stow my weapon as a free object interaction. Does using the component pouch count as an object interaction?

Comment: @JonathanBöcker See here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/127321/40516

Comment: So the answer is, reaching into your oponent pouch is part of casting the spell? That is great, thanks :)